# Review ban for not treating this as "spam or offensive"

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, spam, moderation

After some years of doing edit reviews on SO, I managed to get my first review ban for approving [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23164827/revisions) as non-low quality. It popped up as one of them review audits.

It may be interesting to have a further look at this errand, as I believe there is nothing wrong with the post and I don't understand why a diamond mod deleted it as "spam or offensive".

- The answer posted addresses what the question asks for. It is not some completely unrelated answer, so it is not spam.
- The answer is not offensive.
- It is not a link-only answer as it contains additional information relevant to the question.

The only thing that stands out is that it links to a commercial site. But as far as I can tell, using the commercial service may be the correct answer to the question. It seems unlikely that the person who posted the answer has any interest in advertising for that site.

Is there a SO policy that do not approve with linking commercial content related to the question? If so, shouldn't the edit reviewers be informed about such? (Maybe we were? At least I didn't know of it.) If so, I believe there should exist a different close reason for this?

Or perhaps this is something that's supposed to only concern diamond moderators? And then the blunt, automatic review-audit scripts made it my concern as well?

Comment: Automatic review bans are based on more than just one failure.

Comment: The post was flagged as spam and deleted by a moderator, because the OP didn't reveal their affiliation. It is likely the user posted multiple answers, all with links to the same service. I am actually surprised you didn't see that as spam.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am aware, but the review-audits for anything outside reviewing suggested edits are often very strange. Most of the time when I've managed to not pass one, I just sit there confused. As in this case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Regarding the revealing of affiliation, it does seem like something a diamond mod can know but I can not. If that is the case here, it would seem that this should **not** have popped up as a review audit...

Comment: No, this post is, at the very best, failing to disclose affiliation. I'd have investigated the user further, most likely I'd have flagged it as spam.

Comment: In the majority of cases, moderators respond to flags; someone flagged the post as spam. The user account now is empty, all answers they posted have been deleted, so I cannot determine if this was just one post or a series. But that's the kind of thing I'd investigate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, how? [This is the user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3550657/mark), he has 0 questions 0 answers.

Comment: But *any* post that suggests a specific project or service without disclosing affiliation is *suspect* at best.

Comment: Yes, the user has *zero posts*. That's your *this is probably an audit* signal right there!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Doh, should I review posts according to SO moderation policies or should I review them based on how suspicious they are? Where do I find that delete option? "Your post was deleted because you seem suspicious and you are a new user, so you are likely a spammer or otherwise criminal. In the future, please try not to act suspiciously."

Comment: Again, we cannot now see how widespread this user spammed the site. See [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497) for the policy on spamming. I'd have hoped that a nearly 20k user was familiar with that policy by now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And since I cannot see it, how can I tell if this is just a newbie trying to be helpful or a real spammer? The answer addresses the things asked for in the question.

Comment: Well, that's when you check the user account to see if it is a newbie just trying to be helpful. It is then your choice to leave a comment asking for their affiliation or to flag as spam. Even if you missed the fact that the user has no posts left, *you'd have passed the audit*.

Comment: I am not sure why this has received 4 downvotes. It seems like a genuine post asking for support/explanation. It looks constructive and asks specific questions.

Comment: @mehow: I guess people disagree with the OPs assessment that the audit was invalid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters also your first comment seems off-topic because the OP clearly didn't say he got banned after failing one review. It's his first review ban - see the difference

Comment: @mehow: it is a frequent claim from people getting review-banned that the last failure was their first or first in a long time, I was merely heading that off. The OP indeed doesn't use that defence here, but that doesn't make my comment 'off-topic'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it does not relate to any of the questions the OP has asked within the body of original post. It's just an "attack" and incitement to get this question downvoted.

Comment: @mehow: oh, come on. Who's attacking who here now?

Comment: @mehow: You are a) making assumptions about how *I* voted, b) people's votes are their own. You can disagree with how people vote, but please don't insinuate that I am somehow enticing people how to vote when I try and help out here on Meta.

Comment: @MartijnPieters why do you base your assumptions off reputation? What does one have to do with another? Why would a 20K user have to be familiar with any StackExchange laws? This is a terrible way to look at users, judging people by their reputation? One day you will realize how really "helpful" that is to anyone

Comment: @mehow: reputation is an indication of how long a user has spent on the site and how familiar they are with how the community works. If you review posts, I *do* expect the user to be familiar with that a lot sooner.

Comment: @mehow: For better or worse, reputation is a measure of how much the site trusts someone. I am disappointed when I see that trust violated.

Comment: Reputation is not an indicator of the length of being on site. Reputation is simply a number of votes you've got. I see people with 20K+ who have been on site for just a couple of months, what if you are capable of gaining 20K+ in a week, would you assume the user to be familiar with all the laws and rules? What about people who started participating 5 years ago but didn't bother (for any reason) gaining any rep?

Answer (score 8):

If you see a brand-new user whose only post is a glowing recommendation for a commercial service, with a link to said service, like this:

> [image: Spam example]

be very suspicious about posts like that. To me, even without the other information that I have about this user, that looks like pretty clear spam for a commercial product.

I don't think ["Looks Good"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4787642) is the proper response to something like this. If you didn't feel comfortable with a full spam flag, at least an "other" one that points out why this is really shady-looking would be the right way to deal with this. Moderators could then look into the user and see if we had clearer evidence that this was a spammer.

This was [not the first such incident of spam for this service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023102/how-do-i-securely-sign-data-with-a-timestamp/21500242#21500242), and this group from Pakistan has spammed this service across multiple SE sites. You didn't have that context, but even by itself that post should not have been approved. I agree with the audit case here.

Comment: let me be honest - I would probably fail this audit too. It means it is a good audit but the problem it was very controversial - even for someone with 4+ reviews, tricky one. It's good this has been brought to meta so any future reviewers have a reference to what to do about posts to commercial sites from new users

Comment: @mehow: How does it answer the OP's question, unless it is a product recommendation question and off-topic anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It does not however answer the question "Is there a SO policy that do not approve with linking commercial content related to the question?". Because that's what this boils down to. If there is no such policy, how would this have popped up during a regular review? And who without diamond mod tool access would have flagged this for spam, making it pop up in the edit review queue in the first place? Having the reviewer do research about whether or not a poster is a known spammer each time there is an external link in a post is really to ask too much from us.

Comment: @Lundin - The [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) clearly specifies limits to self-promotion, and while only moderators could confirm that this person was a spammer, you should be highly suspicious of a first post by a 1-rep user that only promotes a commercial product. Spam is not acceptable, even if it somehow happens to answer the question (which sometimes indicates that the question itself is a problem, like was the case for this spam magnet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825462/migration-from-thunderbird-to-outlook ).